# Auto complete creates 'highlighted text' which prevents auto-suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, intellisense, vscode-extensions

As you can see from this video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nLxr.jpg

When I autocomplete 'class' by pressing 'tab' the text I enter will be 'highlighted'.

You can see, 'tw-grid' is suggested, which should auto-complete as the top suggestion by pressing tab again.
However this does not happen, the only way to allow 'tab' to auto complete the top suggestion is to:

1. arrow key down and hit 'tab'
2. press 'esc' or 'tab' and move the cursor back to the text and retype.

Any suggestions to fix this weird highlighting behavior, i would really just like to type 'cl' + tab = class=""

> 

'twg' + tab = class="tw-grid"
Without this constant leaving and re-entering the class block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling this setting:

```
Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions  // default is enabled
```

The issue is that when you `class` it inserts a snippet: `class='|'` with the cursor at the pipe.  So you are still inside a snippet and apparently that is enough to prevent your next typing (`twg`) to focus any suggestion.

Comment: This actually fixed 2 of my unreal clangd fixes I coded lol. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This is it, this worked. Thanks dude. The highlighting remains but it allows me to tab to the top suggestion as requested! Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Space is default keybind for focusSuggestion or...

I had to fix this for my upcoming unreal clangd extension.

```
export const onDidChangeTextDocument = async (e: vscode.TextDocumentChangeEvent) => {

    const currentActiveEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if(e.contentChanges.length === 0 || e.document !== currentActiveEditor?.document){
        return;
    }
 
    const firstContentChange = e.contentChanges[0];

    if(focusSuggestionDelaySetting !== 0 && e.contentChanges.length === 1 && firstContentChange.text.length === 1){
        await delay(focusSuggestionDelaySetting);  // default 350
        await vscode.commands.executeCommand(VSCODE_CMD_FOCUS_SUGGESTION);  // "focusSuggestion"
    }
```